# Error when pip installing Django-Sass-Processor

Tags: python, django, django-models, sass, pip

I get the following error when running the code:

```
pip install libsass django-compressor django-sass-processor
```

Here is the error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\jsooh\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\jsooh\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-htugdym8\\rcssmin_25699a9d5e6f4f74bfe031fe694d8529\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\jsooh\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-htugdym8\\rcssmin_25699a9d5e6f4f74bfe031fe694d8529\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\jsooh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-0h133shl\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\jsooh\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\rcssmin'
         cwd: C:\Users\jsooh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-htugdym8\rcssmin_25699a9d5e6f4f74bfe031fe694d8529\
    Complete output (9 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    copying .\rcssmin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    running build_ext
    building '_rcssmin' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\jsooh\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\jsooh\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-htugdym8\\rcssmin_25699a9d5e6f4f74bfe031fe694d8529\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\jsooh\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-htugdym8\\rcssmin_25699a9d5e6f4f74bfe031fe694d8529\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\jsooh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-0h133shl\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\jsooh\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\rcssmin' Check the logs for full command 
output.
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks, and please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+error%3A+Microsoft+Visual+C%2B%2B+14.0+is+required

Answer (score 1):

The error is that you need Microsoft visual c++ 14.0 so I suggest you download that.

Download : https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

> ```
> error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
> ```

Thank You :)